# How to get all timestamps for a specific date? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I have rows in a MySQL database, and each has a timestamp value. (ie 1340296188)

I am trying to find all entries for the last 7 days. I know how to do a query to find all WITHIN the last 7 days, something like:

```
$lastweek = time() - 604800;
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp > $lastweek");
```

However, I need to be able to get each day seperately. How would I do this query? I don't know how to find from the above results which ones are for which specific date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there already; you just need to parse the timestamp field in `$results`.

A day is (60 * 60 * 24) seconds, so you can divide each row's timestamp field by 86400, turn it into an integer, and the result is the number of days ago that this entry occurred.

For each row in your dataset:

```
$daysAgo = int($row["timestamp"] / 86400);
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is more then one way to do this. Here's one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
GROUP BY DAY(timestamp)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to query all the results for a week, I can do that. I'm trying to seperate all the results by day.

Comment: `GROUP BY` should take care of that. My untested update *should* work